# Add letter to setnames in data.table R

Tags: r, data.table

What is the simplest way to change the colnames of a data.table in such a way that the original name is kept but preceded (or followed) by one or a few other letters. 
E.g. I'm running the following code

```
tmp <- DT[, lapply(.SD, mean, na.rm=T), by = .(NACE2), .SDcols=cols]
tmp1 <- DT[, lapply(.SD, sum, na.rm=T), by = .(NACE2), .SDcols=cols]
sna <- function(x) { sum(!is.na(x))}
tmp2 <- DT[, lapply(.SD, sna), by = .(NACE2), .SDcols=cols]
```

This results in multiple data.tables which all have the same names determined by the original names in `DT`, which has 65 selected columns via `.SDcols`
I would like to change the colnames before merging `tmp, tmp1, tmp2` together in such a way that the names are preceded respectively by

1. m_  for `tmp`
2. s_  for `tmp1`
3. na_ for `tmp2`

Is there a way of doing this directly in the `lapply` function or a better way than avoiding retyping 65 names via `setnames(tmp, ...)` ?
I know it is possible to create a vector of the colnames and then combine that vector with another vector consisting of e.g. "m_" but there must be a more sensible way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `paste` with `setnames` to change the column names

```
setnames(tmp, paste0("m_", names(tmp)))
```

and similarly

```
setnames(tmp1, paste0("s_", names(tmp1)))
setnames(tmp2, paste0("na_", names(tmp2)))
```